# Changing data types twice in one conditional statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, types, casting

Pretty basic question, but I am trying to write a simple while loop in which I first need an input as int.
But in order to break out of said loop, I want to be able to write 'quit' which is a string. How do I do this?

```
active = True
while active:
    age = int(input("Please state your age: "))
    if age < 3:
        print("The ticket is free.\n")
    elif 3 <= age <= 12:
        print("The ticket is 10 dollars.\n")
    elif age > 12:
        print("The ticket is 15 dollars.\n")
    elif age == 'quit':
        print("Quit program")
        active = False
```

I tried putting the age in the last elif in a str(age) function, which I believed would turn input age back to a string, but it gives a value error. Any tips?

Comment: Don't convert the input to an `int` upfront. `"quit"` is not a valid integer, so that will always raise a `ValueError` when you try to input it.

Comment: read the input, check if its "quit" and if its not, typecast it to int after that ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check if `age` is a string first, then check if it is an integer. You're getting a `ValueError` because you're calling `int(input())`, which causes the error when the input is not an integer. You can first check if the string is `"quit"` before continuing with the program and also to prevent `ValueError`'s from occurring even if the user types something that isn't `"quit"` or an integer, wrap the rest of the code in a `try ... except ...`.

```py
active = True
while active:
    age_input = input("Please state your age: ")
    if age_input == 'quit':
        print("Quit program")
        active = False
    else:
        try:
            age = int(age_input)
            if age < 3:
                print("The ticket is free.\n")
            elif 3 <= age <= 12:
                print("The ticket is 10 dollars.\n")
            elif age > 12:
                print("The ticket is 15 dollars.\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter an integer or 'quit'.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the `ValueError` exception, but why always raise an exception casting the `str` into `int` when it is not needed to raise it?
The best approach is to use `isdecimal()`:

```
active = True
while active:
    age_input = input("Please state your age: ")
    if age_input == 'quit':
        print("Quit program")
        active = False
    elif age_input.isdecimal():
        age = int(age_input)
        if age < 3:
            print("The ticket is free.\n")
        elif 3 <= age <= 12:
            print("The ticket is 10 dollars.\n")
        else:
            print("The ticket is 15 dollars.\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter an integer or 'quit'.\n")
```

[More info](https://miguendes.me/python-isdigit-isnumeric-isdecimal#how-isdigit-works-and-when-to-use-it)

It doesn't seem `active` variable is needed. You could use `while True` and then use `quit()` or `exit()` when "quit" is detected. [See more info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/)